# Using list elements in TrackedSymbols for Dynamic

Tags: list-manipulation, dynamic

During the execution of the following code a column of three lists
and two sliders are displaying in output.
The first list updates if either a or b changes.
The second list updates only if the value of a is changed.
Similarly, the third list updates only if the value of b is changed.

```
a = 0;
b = 0;
Column[
{
  Dynamic[{a, b}, TrackedSymbols :> {a,b}],
  Dynamic[{a, b}, TrackedSymbols :> {a}],
  Dynamic[{a, b}, TrackedSymbols :> {b}],
  Slider[Dynamic[a], {0, 1}],
  Slider[Dynamic[b], {0, 1}]
}
]
```

Next I would like to replace {a,b} by a list x with two elements:

```
x = {0, 0};
Column[
{
  Dynamic[{x[[1]], x[[2]]}, TrackedSymbols :> {x}],
  Dynamic[{x[[1]], x[[2]]}, TrackedSymbols :> {x[[1]]}],
  Dynamic[{x[[1]], x[[2]]}, TrackedSymbols :> {x[[2]]}],
  Slider[Dynamic[x[[1]]], {0, 1}],
  Slider[Dynamic[x[[2]]], {0, 1}]
}
]
```

It is easy to check that now only the first list updates.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: My first thought is that `x[[1]]` is not a `Symbol`.  The dynamic updating system probably only tracks symbols, not parts of them, so probably you can't do it the second way.

Comment: I believe `TrackedSymbols` must be taken strictly; i.e., it accepts only symbols, not expressions.

Comment: I presume you are aware that you can write `{a, b} = {0, 0}` in your first example, so I ask: why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: @m_goldberg, thank you for your comment.
I want to write a code, which manipulates a big list (say 20 elements). I want to display the list and update it only when its first element is changes. Moreover, I don't want to use additional "tester" variables like `Dynamic[x[[1]], (x[[1]] = tester = #1) &]` ... `TrackedSymbols :> {tester}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own list of symbols with `Unique`.

```
Clear[x];
nVars = 20;
x = Table[Unique[x], {nVars}];
vars = Map[Hold, OwnValues@x, {-1}][[-1, -1]]
(# = 0.) & /@ x; 

(* {Hold[x$363], Hold[x$364], ...} *)
```

It's convenient to store the held variables, since once they are initialized, it's tricky to get the symbols unevaluated.  We can get at the symbols via various tricks:

```
vars[[2]] /. Hold[var_] :> (TrackedSymbols :> {var}
(* --> TrackedSymbols :> {x$364} *)

Dynamic @@ vars[[3]]]
(* --> Dynamic[x$364] *)
```

Here's an example like the one in the question.

```
Grid[Transpose@
  {Table[Dynamic[x, #] &[vars[[i]] /. Hold[var_] :> (TrackedSymbols :> {var})],
     {i, Length@x}],
    Table[Slider[Dynamic @@ vars[[i]]], {i, Length@x}]}
]
```

Here's the output for `nVars = 4`, where each slider has been clicked once in turn:

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: Thank you for your smart trick. I would like to ask you, what is the role of the Refresh function ?
Namely, why you don't use shorter possibility like this

`Table[Slider[Dynamic @@ vars[[i]]], {i, Length@x}]`

`Table[Dynamic[x, Evaluate[vars[[i]] /. Hold[var_]:> (TrackedSymbols :> {var})]], {i, Length@x}]`

Comment: Actually what confuses me is why I seem to have to inject `TrackedVariables` in there twice.  Doing it once does not always work. In any case, your example does not work for me from a fresh kernel in V9.0.1.  For the first `Dynamic[x,...]`, I get symbols `x$363` etc. that are never updated.  Of all the variations I tried, only the one with `Refresh` worked in all cases.  I'm afraid I have not completely figured out why yet.

Comment: It is amasing, but I got such problem with your version.
By the way, if I evaluate the code twice, the symbols are starting to uptate.
I use also V9.0.1.
In my example the sliders are constructed first. Maybe they initialize the sybols and the updating becomes possible ?

Comment: @VahagnPoghosyan Oops, I forgot to copy the initialization line -- your comment made me notice.  Now it should work.  I'm not sure why the symbols need initialization.  For instance `{Dynamic@y, Slider[Dynamic@y]}` does not need to have `y` initialized beforehand.

Comment: I must be missing something; why don't you merely define `vars = Hold /@ x` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  It started as extra protection, since I was fiddling with things out of order.  If the `x$nnn` are already initialized, `Hold /@ x` will hold their values, not the symbols.  If you're willing to assume that the lines will be executed exactly as presented, then `vars = Hold /@ x` works fine.  But if in the OP's application, things might happen in a different order, then this more robust definition seems a better way to go.

Comment: > I'm not sure why the symbols need initialization. For instance {Dynamic@y, Slider[Dynamic@y]} does not need to have y initialized beforehand.
******
@MichaelE2 I think it comes from the fact that `vars[[i]]` represents held variable. Unfortunately it is not possible to use variables in the form `Symbol["x"<>ToString[i]]`. Always we get message "Tag Symbol in Symbol["x1"] is Protected".

Comment: @VahagnPoghosyan  The expression returned to the front end has ``Dynamic[$CellContext`x$179095]`` in it -- the `vars[[i]]` are replaced in the kernel before they are sent back to the front end.  The returned output looks the same to me for the `y` slider as for the `x` sliders.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The mechanism of the calculations is very strange, but I solved this problem via Evaluate function: 

`Table[Dynamic[Evaluate[x], Evaluate[vars[[i]] /. Hold[var_] :> (TrackedSymbols :> {var})]], {i, Length@x}]`

Comment: @VahagnPoghosyan Yes, that is equivalent to `Dynamic[x, #]&[vars[[i]] /. Hold[var_] :> (TrackedSymbols :> {var})]`, which I tried.  I think my inclusion of `Refresh` may be a red-herring, as you questioned earlier -- now removed.  I can't find the conditions that led to an error.  All the ways seem to need  variables in `x` to be initialized for them to work.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Very good ! Now it works for all initial states of the kernel !

Answer (score 2):

Using the ideas/tricks/solutions given in comments, I arrived to the following compact code, which uses only the variables x, x1, x2, ...

```
nVars = 10;
Clear @@ Names["x" ~~ DigitCharacter ...]
x = Table[ToExpression["x" <> ToString[i], InputForm], {i, 1, nVars}]

Column[Table[
ToExpression["x" <> ToString[i], InputForm, Hold] /. Hold[var_] :>
    Dynamic[Evaluate[x], TrackedSymbols :> {var}]
, {i, 1, nVars}]]

Column[Table[
ToExpression["x" <> ToString[i], InputForm, Hold] /. Hold[var_] :> Slider[Dynamic[var]]
, {i, 1, nVars}]]
```

Comment: Feel free to unaccept mine and accept your own.  I think it is better, and future visitors would appreciate having the best answer marked.  Unless someone else posts an even better solution.

Comment: @MichaelE2, this answer is based on the ideas of your answer and comments. Both answers are acceptable for me.